# PHP multiple variables

Tags: php, variables

I am learning some php right now. Is there a way to define a variable with multiple variables?

Something like:

```
$name = "John"
$lastname = "Doe"
$number = "017434234"

$user = $name,$lastname,$number
```

Of corse this script does not work. Which is the correct way?

Comment: As an array? `$user = [$name,$lastname,$number]; var_dump($user);`?

Comment: Concat them. $user = $name.$lastname.$number;

Comment: Depends, what are you trying to do? Defining a variable with multiple variables does not mean much. You want to concatenate them? Create an array?

Comment: add semicolon at the end of variable deceleration and concate them using `$user = $name.",".$lastname.",".$number;`

Comment: Are you learning PHP, or are you learning programming at all? Because you should have a basic knowledge of programming structures. Like arrays.

Comment: Learning PHP :-) I know the basics like HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put them together, the dot concatenates the variables:

```
$user = $name.$lastname.$number;
```

If you want to define multiple strings, you can use an array:

```
$user = ["John", "Doe", "123"];
```

Or you can use keys in your array to give them meaning:

```
$user = [firstname => "John", lastname => "Doe"];
echo $user->firstname; //gives John
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was quite easy :-)

Comment: ... or build a `User` class instead of an associative array for structured objects

Answer (score 0):

Awesome that youre learning PHP :)

You can make it an array like this whit a function, of course.. this is a little more "over complicated" than the example above.

Script:

```
//Function array with inputting and selecting what to return:
function MyArray($Firstname, $Lastname, $Number, $OutPutWhat){

   //Create an array:
   $Array = array(
       'FirstName' => "$Firstname",
       'LastName' => "$Lastname",
       'Number' => "$Number"
   );
       //Return the arrayValue[ofthis]
       return $Array[$OutPutWhat];
}

 //Echo out the value
echo MyArray("John", "Doe", "1234567", 'FirstName');  //Outputs the firstname
```